# Memory leak occurs when opening nested parallelism

Tags: gcc, parallel-processing, memory-leaks, openmp, nvidia

On Nvidia Tegra platform(Xavier, TX2, Nano), the memory usage keeps growing, from 3MB to over 1GB.
After doing enough exploration, the bug seems comes from gcc's gomp library,
because after replacing the gomp with LLVM openmp, the memory leak problem disappears.

> 1. No memory leak in 5.4.0 in PC
> 2. No memory leak in platform other than Nvidia with arm CPU for GCC 7.3.0(re-compiling gcc in Nvidia is too complicated and time consuming, so haven't tried on that)
> 3. Memory leak when using a self-compiled newer version of gomp

- GCC version: 7.5.0
- OS: Ubuntu 18.04

This is the smallest example that can reproduce the problem:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
#include "omp.h"

int main() {
  omp_set_nested(1); /* probably memory leak */
#pragma omp parallel for num_threads(2)
  for (int sec = 0; sec < 2; sec++) {
    if (sec == 0) {
      while(1);
    } else {
      while(1) {
#pragma omp parallel for
        for (long i = 0; i < 2; i++) {}
      }
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

```
    g++ mem_leak.cpp -fopenmp && ./a.out
```

```
    The omp_set_nested(1) is a deprecated function according to the
    document, but I can not find any alternatives, nested parallelism is
    used frequently, can anyone help to solve this memory leak problem?
```

Comment: Since OpenMP 3.0 instead of `omp_set_nested` function you can use [omp_set_max_active_levels](https://www.openmp.org/spec-html/5.1/openmpsu134.html#x173-2060003.2.15) function or [OMP_MAX_ACTIVE_LEVELS](https://www.openmp.org/spec-html/5.1/openmpse65.html#x331-5060006.8) environment variable.  If the [OMP_NUM_THREADS](https://www.openmp.org/spec-html/5.1/openmpse59.html#x325-5000006.2) environment variable is set to a comma-separated list of more than one value, it also enables nested parallelism.

Comment: As you seem to have demonstrated a bug in GCC you should probably submit a bug report to them, rather than telling everyone here and hoping that someone on the GCC libomp team notices... (See https://gcc.gnu.org/bugs/ )

Comment: As a workaround you can try using tasks. Tasks are usually better from performance point of view than nested parallelism.